# Send Custom Android App to Customer

Tags: android, installation, sharing, apk

I Developed a Bluetooth app that we now offer but a customer requested some customization.  I have completed the customization but do not want to put it on the market since we charged him $100.00 for changes and I don't want other people downloading it for free(doesnt seem fair to him).  How can I send the app to him so he can easily install it?  He is not a developer so does not have eclipse to install the app.

Sorry for such an easy question but all I saw was people sharing apps with friends who already have eclipse.

Thank you,
Travis

Comment: put in somewhere and give him the download link and then ask him to go to that URL and once its downloaded he's just a click away from installing it..

Comment: zip the apk and send it via email.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like the others have said, send the `apk` file by e-mail and ask him to install it. If you don't want him to send the apk to others, you could try pairing the package to his device number/id, or google account, or anything else. Of course, you should implement that in code, preferably in a secure way (for you and for him).

You may need to give him instructions to enable "**Install from unknown sources**" in the settings, in his device.

Comment: David,Thank you for the response.  May be a silly question but how will he get the app installed?  Would I send it to him via email he can access through his phone then he can open the attachment there or should he connect the phone to his computer and drag the app to the phone like you would to a thumb drive?

Comment: No, it's even easier. No computer involved. Send the apk to his email. He will open the apk as an attachment on his own device, and the system will ask him to install the apk. It's like opening any attachment on his own phone, really.